# Nuxt SPA for multiple pages

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to be able to use the nuxt pages feature and compile it into a single page app, possibly via a virtual dom. So each page will still be available via nuxtlink, but not by URL or file destination.

I am trying to create a web app that can be hosted on my C# app locally. I am eventually going to distribute this app. The Nuxt website will communicate with the API also served locally. I am writing a static Nuxt app, but it is becoming increasingly difficult to show and hide all the components of a complicated app in one page. The reason I want to keep it to one page is to keep user flow, and prevent bugs where a user visits a page via url that shouldnt be accessible normally causing complications in my API.

If there are ways in nuxt to check if a users origin is redirected from Nuxt or from simply typing the URL that would provide an alternative fix to my problem - but I havent found anything yet. This may also be complicated I assume as keeping track of a users location on the website not easy - and it is important not to allow a user to skip a login page for example as this will be released privately.

I am using vite and nuxt and I am compiling to a static page and my aim is to have a single html file.

Currently I am using a very makeshift way of switching pages. Each "page" is a component, which hides itself

```js
:class="{'dissapear': done}
```

```html
<script setup>
let done = ref(false)
function hide(){
    done.value = true
}
</script>
```

Every component is shown in the index, and hidden once its done its purpose.

This stops me from changing pages at will when outside the component, and gets complicated having every element in a single page.